# Units of Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: field-theory, dimensional-analysis, si-units, klein-gordon-equation

I'm looking at the units of the Klein-Gordon equation
$$u_{tt} - c^2\Delta u = -\frac{m^2c^2}{\hbar^2}u.
$$
Disregarding the units of $u$, which are the same everywhere and so cancel, I get $seconds^{-2}$ for both terms on the LHS, but $meters^{-2}$ on the RHS. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a $c^2$ on the RHS, equation should be

$$
\color{red}{\frac{1}{c^2}}u_{tt} - \Delta u = -\frac{m^2 c^2}{\hbar^2}u
$$

Or equivalently

$$
u_{tt} - c^2\Delta u = -\frac{m^2 \color{red}{c^4}}{\hbar^2}u
$$